# Filter an attribute LDAP against current date in LDAP SEARCH

Tags: ldap

how to exclude from a LDAP search, users with a `date attribute < current date ?`

Comment: It depends on the date attribute.

Answer (score 1):

A LDAP filter similar to:

```
ldapsearch -D "cn=exampleuser,example.com" -w secret -p 389 -h server.example.com -b "dc=example,dc=com" -s sub "(createTimestamp<=20200101500000Z)"
```

Should work. Where 20200101500000Z is the current date.